# Cant figure out my logic error Java

Tags: java, logic

When i go to run this the value it returns is twice the currentStation plus the incremental value. Instead of just the currentStation plus incremental value. I cant figure out if its a problem in AutoRadioSystem or the Radio class.

```
public class AutoRadioSystem
{

  private Radio selectedRadio;
  private AMRadio radioAM = new AMRadio();
  private FMRadio radioFM = new FMRadio(); 
  private XMRadio radioXM = new XMRadio();

  public AutoRadioSystem()
  {
    selectedRadio = new AMRadio();
  }
  public double getCurrentStation()
  {
    if (selectedRadio.equals(radioAM))
    {
      return radioAM.getCurrentStaion();
    }
    else if (selectedRadio.equals(radioFM))
    {
      return radioFM.getCurrentStaion();
    }
    else if (selectedRadio.equals(radioXM))
    {
      return radioXM.getCurrentStaion();
    }
    return 0.0;
  }
  public void selectRadio()
  {
    if (selectedRadio.equals(radioAM))
      selectedRadio = radioFM;
    else if (selectedRadio.equals(radioFM))
      selectedRadio = radioXM;
    else if (selectedRadio.equals(radioXM))
      selectedRadio = radioAM;  
  }

  public void upCategory()
  {
    double catUp = radioXM.getCurrentStaion();
    catUp += 10;
    if (catUp > 199.0)
    {
      catUp = 1; 
      radioXM.setCurrentStation(catUp);
    }
    radioXM.setCurrentStation(catUp);
  }

  public void up()
  {
   if (selectedRadio.equals(radioAM))
    {
      double stationUp = radioAM.getCurrentStaion();
      stationUp += radioAM.getIncrement();
      radioAM.setCurrentStation(stationUp);
      // System.out.println(stationUp );
  }
  }
  public boolean equals (Object o) 
  {
    if (o == null) 
      return false; 
    if (! (o instanceof AutoRadioSystem)) 
      return false; 
    AutoRadioSystem other = (AutoRadioSystem) o; 
    return this.selectedRadio == other.selectedRadio;
  }

  public static void main (String [] args) { 
    AutoRadioSystem c = new AutoRadioSystem();
    c.selectRadio();
    double b = c.getCurrentStation();
    System.out.println(b);
    c.selectRadio();
    double d = c.getCurrentStation();
    System.out.println(d);
    c.upCategory();
    double f = c.getCurrentStation();
    System.out.println(f);
    c.selectRadio();
    double e = c.getCurrentStation();
    System.out.println(e);
    c.up();
    double g = c.getCurrentStation();
    System.out.println(g);
    c.up();
    double t = c.getCurrentStation();
    System.out.println(t);
  }
}
```

additional code

```
public class AMRadio extends Radio
{
  private static final double Max_Station = 1605;
  private static final double Min_Station = 535;
  private static final double Increment = 10;
  public AMRadio()
  {
  }
  public  double getMax_Station()
  {
    return this.Max_Station;
  }
  public  double getMin_Station()
  {
    return this.Min_Station;
  }
  public  double getIncrement()
  {
    return this.Increment;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    String message = ("AM " + this.currentStation);
    return message;
  } 

}


public abstract class Radio 
{
 double currentStation;

 RadioSelectionBar radioSelectionBar;
 public Radio()
 {
   this.currentStation = getMin_Station();
 }
 public abstract double getMax_Station();
 public abstract double getMin_Station();
 public abstract double getIncrement();
 public void up()
 {

 }

 public void down()
 {

 }

 public double getCurrentStaion()
 {
   return this.currentStation;
 }
 public void setCurrentStation(double freq)
 {
   currentStation += freq;
 }
 public void setStation(int buttonNumber, double station)
 {
 }
 public double getStation(int buttonNumber)
 {
   return 0.0;
 }
 public String toString()
 {
   String message = ("" + currentStation);
   return message;
 } 
  public boolean equals (Object o) 
  {
    if (o == null) 
      return false; 
    if (! (o instanceof Radio)) 
      return false; 
    Radio other = (Radio) o; 
    return this.currentStation == other.currentStation;
  }
```

Comment: Have you been taught or learned how to use a debugger? It'll save your life. Also, unit tests might help point out incorrectly implemented components.

Comment: we haven't our teacher hasn't got to that yet.

Comment: This is bad practice on SO, but let's go step by step. What happens the first time you call `c.selectRadio();`? What are the methods and objects involved?

Comment: why don't you google how to debug? If yr using eclipse this is the link http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: It checks to see what radio its currently on, since its on AM it moves to FM, that I have working fine. I've tested it and it moves through all of them. Next I call up(). This is supposed to check what station its currently on according to which radio its on. Its supposed to call radioFM.getCurrent Station to and add the increment to it using radioFM.getIncrement.From there it sets the currentStation to the new station. I modeled it after my upCategory method which it currently working.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is below method:

```
public void setCurrentStation(double freq)
 {
   // This is equal to currentStation = currentStation + freq
   currentStation += freq;
 }
```

it should be

```
public void setCurrentStation(double freq)
 {
   currentStation = freq;
 }
```

Because you have already adding `currentStation` in `up` method.

Just suggestions, not really related to question:

- Think about 'selectRadio' method. What is the intention of having it.
- You have `Radio` as property and other three implementation of this class as well. I think you should consider using 'instance of` operator.